Construct confidence interval for $\mu_X-\mu_Y$ with different and unknown variances
I am self-studying for my course about statistic, then I've occurred this problem in the past exam papers (no solutions).
Problem:
Given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be an independent random sample drawn from $N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ be an independent random sample drawn from $N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$, and assume the two random samples are independent. Also given $$U=\frac{\overline{X}-\overline{Y}-(\mu_X-\mu_Y)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_X^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{m}}}\sim N(0,1)$$ and $$V_1=\frac{n S_X^2}{\sigma_X^2}\sim\chi_{n-1}^2,V_2=\frac{mS_Y^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\sim \chi_{m-1}^2,V=V_1+V_2$$Find a $90\%$ confidence interval for $\mu_X-\mu_Y$ assuming $U$ and $V$ are independent, $\frac{\sigma_X^2}{\sigma_Y^2}=d$ for some constant $d$.
My attempt:
The interval can be easily construct if $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2$, thus consider $Z_i=\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{d}}\sim N(\frac{\mu_X}{\sqrt{d}},\sigma_Y^2)$. Then I got $$U=\frac{\sqrt{d}\cdot\overline{Z}-\overline{Y}-(\mu_X-\mu_Y)}{\sqrt{\frac{d\cdot\sigma_Y^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{m}}}\sim N(0,1)$$$$V_1=\frac{nS_Z^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$$However I am stuck, as I can't think of any way to get rid of $\sqrt{d}$ infront of $\overline{Z}$ and $d$ in the denominator.
My final question: As I am new to Cross Validated, is there a website that can assist me in searching for questions? (Such as Approach0 for Math Stack Exchange).

Your lasr Q: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/faq-best-practices-for-searching-cv  The following stored search could help you
